# combining math accents in plainTeX vs LaTeX

Tags: plain-tex, accents

When typesetting math accents, I have the impression that LaTeX does sometimes a better job than plain. My question is, what does LaTeX differently and whether there is an easy fix also for plain.

The issues I know about are:

1. Plain does not move the accents to the right for some fonts (e.g. the script fonts). Is this a problem of the package that loads the fonts? (Btw. usually `\cal` is fine, while `\script` is wrong.)
2. When combining two accents, plain moves the first one to the right, but not the second one.

As a demonstration, compare the following two results. I use the kp-fonts as they have quite large shift for math accents (a bit too large for my taste I have to say).

plain code:

```
\input kp-fonts

$\tilde x, \bar x, \bar{\tilde x}, \tilde{\bar x}, \tilde{\script C}$

\bye
```

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}

$\tilde x, \bar x, \bar{\tilde x}, \tilde{\bar x}, \tilde{\mathscr{C}}$

\end{document}
```

Results:

[image: Result for plainTeX code]  vs.  [image: Result for LaTeX code]

Comment: The difference between plain TeX `\script C` and LaTeX `\mathscr C` is: plainTeX uses `rsfs10` with skewchar unset but LaTeX uses `jkpsyd.tfm` with skewchar 0. I can write an answer (if you want) how to correct plain TeX code, but only concerned to the `\tilde{\script C}`. The double accents are another story and you have found the plain TeX solution at OPmac trick page.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with some kind of a solution for the second problem. Modifying the trick from http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#colaccent one can define

```
\newmuskip\tmpmudim 
\newdimen\tmpdim

\def\accents#1#2#3{
  {\ifnum\skewchar\textfont1<0 \tmpmudim=0mu \else \calculatemukern {#3}{\char\skewchar\textfont1}\fi 
   \mkern2\tmpmudim #1{\mkern-2\tmpmudim{#2#3}}} 
} 
\def\calculatemukern #1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{\the\textfont1 #1#2}\setbox1=\hbox{\the\textfont1 #1\null#2}% 
  \tmpdim=\wd0 \advance\tmpdim by-\wd1 
  \tmpmudim=\expandafter\ignorept\the\tmpdim mu \tmpmudim=288\tmpmudim 
  \tmpdim=16em \divide\tmpmudim by\expandafter\ignorefracpart\the\tmpdim\relax 
} 
\def\ignorefracpart#1.#2\relax{#1} 
{\lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t  \lowercase{\gdef\ignorept#1?!{#1}}}
```

Then it is enough to write

```
$\accents\bar\tilde x, \accents\tilde\bar x$
```

to get the right result.

But it would be nice if it worked somehow automatically.